# C# Linq syntax naming

Tags: c#, linq

In some cases I see LINQ written this way:

```
L.Select(_ => _.A).Where(...)
```

and in some other cases, I see this:

```
A = from B in C where (...)
```

Do these two syntaxes have different names?
I understand both, but they seem to be referred to as LINQ so I am a bit confused.

Comment: ok, I get it now; when I google something with LINQ, I often find samples with the first style

Comment: i mean both could be called _LINQ_ considering they're declarative and similar to SQL queries _in a way_ regardless of the method syntax or query syntax.

Comment: note, though, that the *libraries* and *general approach* **also** (right or wrong) gets labelled as LINQ - so it would also be true to say that *even though* you're not using the "language integrated" part, you're still using LINQ features

Comment: The first approach is called lambda syntax and then second one is query syntax

Comment: @stuard, I realize it is a duplicate of the question you linked; I hadn't found it; you can close this one I guess. Thanks everyone for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

The first one is Method Syntax or Method extension syntax or Fluent
The second one is Query Syntax or Query Expression Syntax